# Using align and tag inline together

Tags: align

Is there a way to use `align` and `tag` inline together? Here are some examples of what I tried:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{aligned}
x^2 &= 1 \\
x   &= -1,1 \tag{*} \\
\end{aligned}$$

\end{document}
```

It gives me an error, however, telling me `\tag not allowed`.

Comment: `\begin{align}` inside `$$` will generate an error (and you should not use `$$` in latex anyway). Perhaps you are looking for the first example, but without `$$` (hard to tell from your question.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter which one I use. I did realize that only `\begin{aligned}` works inside the `$$`. but the problem is that it doesn't accept tags. Here's the error I get: `\tag not allowed here`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for clearing it up (I realized why my question was unclear from your comment). I updated my question so it's not as unclear.

Comment: you can't number inline  math as an equation?

Comment: Your new MWE produces `! LaTeX Error: Environment aligned undefined.`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. I sometimes need to use tags to explain what I'm doing in certain equations (or label them as `a` or something), so I needed to use tags. I assume it isn't possible, then? I have no idea why it produces an error... I'll just leave it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `align` or `align*` (and never use `$$` in latex).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x^2 &= 1 \\
x   &= -1,1 \tag{*} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```